# Unit-testing iOS app syncronization logic

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I've recently adopted an iOS corporate app that acts as a client to a media CMS.  Put another way, the web app manages a catalog of videos, image slide shows, and static/offline HTML files.  The iOS app connects to the web app and downloads this content to itself for offline usage.

The hot spot is the synchronization logic between the iOS and web applications.  Is there any advice for unit-testing the logic between these two projects?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you have to "cheat" some.  One way to do this is to use `NSRunLoop`'s `runUntilDate:` method, and this was my approach.

Basically, to give your web code a chance to communicate with the web, you want to put your Unit-Test into a sort of busy-wait that actually lets everyone do some work, but you also want to "check back" in your Unit-Test periodically to see whether your operation is done.

Here's my "go do work" method:

```
-(BOOL)runLooperDooper:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutInSeconds{
    NSDate* giveUpDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeoutInSeconds];
    // loop until the operation completes and sets stopRunLoop = TRUE
    // or until the timeout has expired
    // stopRunLoop is a instance variable of the UnitTest object... take care to reset at the start or end of each test!
    while (!stopRunLoop && [giveUpDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) 
    {
        // run the current run loop for 1.0 second(s) to give the operation code a chance to work
        NSDate *stopDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:stopDate];
    }

    return stopRunLoop;
}
```

So, in each Unit-Test:

```
   NSTimeInterval testSpecificTimeout = 60; //60 seconds or however long you need...
   [self runLooperDooper:testSpecificTimeout]; 
   STAssertTrue(stopRunLoop, @"Failed to complete before runloop expired after %f seconds", timeoutInSeconds);
```

Then, I also registered some event-handlers for my web-code to know when its operations were finished by setting the `stopRunLoop` ivar to `TRUE`.